# Get firestore data as array

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im tryng to display firestore data but I just get one value. I have try forEach and map. Nothing is working. Heres my code:

````
  React.useEffect(() => {
    retrieveNetwork();
  }, []);

const retrieveNetwork = async () => {
    try {
      const q = query(collection(db, "cities", uidx, "adress"));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      let result = [];

      //querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => setGas(doc.data().home));
      querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        result.push(doc.data().home);
        setGas(result);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `.map` method returns an array (official docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), so you could do something like this:

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    retrieveNetwork();
  }, []);

const retrieveNetwork = async () => {
  try {
    const q = query(collection(db, "cities", uidx, "adress"));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    // an array from the docs filled only with "home" data
    const results = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      return doc.data().home;
    });
    
    // only update the state once per invokation
    setGas(results)

  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I still getting an object instead of an array. Can you still help me? Sory and thanks!

Comment: @AndresPelaez the map function should always return an array, what do you see when you console.log results?